# Compare values from a file to a column in Excel and update another column

Tags: excel, vba

An Excel sheet exists with a list of machine names in Column A in Sheet1.

A text file exists with a list of machines that are decommissioned.

I need to mark all the decommissioned machines as "DECOM" in the Excel sheet under column B on the same Sheet (Sheet1).

Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub ImportTextFileContents()
Dim strg As Variant
Dim EntireLine As String

FName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Choose File to Import")

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1
i = 1
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, EntireLine
    strg = EntireLine

    If (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A").Value = strg) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "DECOM"
    End If

    i = i + 1
Wend
EndMacro:

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you import the contents of the file to the spreadsheet and then use a formula (like `countif`)? I think that it is much more easier.

Comment: Probably preferable to avoid importing data to the spreadsheet, or creating temporary spreadsheets that need to be killed later on, for efficiency's sake. Also, OP would need to use a MATCH function test, not CountIf function in order to identify the machines listed in the TXT file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub ImportTextFileContents()
Dim strg As Variant
Dim EntireLine As String
Dim DecomMachines() as String
Dim rngExcel as Range
Dim cell as Range

FName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Choose File to Import")

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

'Create an array to contain the list of Decommissioned machines from the TXT file

i = 1
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, EntireLine
    strg = EntireLine
    ReDim Preserve DecomMachines(0 to i-1)
    DecomMachines(i-1) = strg   
    i = i + 1
Wend    

'Set the range variable over which we need to iterate:
Set rngExcel = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)  '<-- modify as needed  

For each cell in rngExcel    
'Check to see if this cell.value exists in the array we built, above:
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cstr(cell.Value),DecomMachines,False)) Then
        'if the name exists in the DecomMachines array, then we need to mark it as decommissioned.
        cell.Offset(0,1).Value = "DECOM"
    Else:
        'it doesnot exist in the TXT file, so ignore it
    End If
Next    

EndMacro:

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Close #1
End Sub
```

This creates an array that contains all of the machines identified in the TXT file, and then iterates over the range of cells in Column A, testing to see if each cell value exists in the array. If it does exist, then we know to mark it as decommissioned in column B (`cell.Offset(0,1)`) and if it does not exist, we just move on to the next cell in column A.

Comment: This worked exactly like I want...with some minor additions that were needed. Thank you David!